# Powershell cmdlet reference for Kubernetes powershell module

Tags: powershell, kubernetes

Where can I see the cmdlet reference for k8s module [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSKubectl/0.13.0)?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/felixfbecker/PSKubectl ?

Comment: There is a link on the left side called "Project site". It leads to @Daniel's link. 
You can poke around there and find your answers ;)

Comment: Thanks guys. When I run those commands, I get an error

Get-KubeDeployment
Get-KubeDeployment: Unable to list Deployment (apps/v1) resources (HTTP status Forbidden).
Forbidden: deployments.apps is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default"

Comment: Do you have the same error when doing `kubectl get deployments`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility.

As already mentioned in the comments, the reference you are seeking can be found [here](https://github.com/felixfbecker/PSKubectl) (the `Project Site` link on the left side of the [module page](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSKubectl/0.13.0)).